# Loop through setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.testimonial1').css("display", "none");
    $('.testimonial2').css("display","block");
} ,3000);

setTimeout(function(){
  $('.testimonial2').css('display', 'none');
  $('.testimonial3').css('display', 'block');
}, 6000);


});
```

The issue is that it only run once. I would like after the second timeout, it loops back to the first timeout, and so forth.

For any clarification, kindly advise.

Comment: You want to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) instead.

Comment: On another note, since timing isn't the most precise of things, your two functions might not stay synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setInterval` function in JQuery.

Here is a working example : [JSFiddle setInterval](http://jsfiddle.net/dineshchitlangia/bnm5j5ft/6/)

**EDIT 1:**
Updated JSFiddle link with fadeIn/fadeOut effects and added the code below:

Javascript

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#t1').fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $('.testimonial1').css("display", "none");
        });
        $('#t2').fadeIn("slow", function () {
            $('.testimonial2').css("display", "block");
        });
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#t2').fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $('.testimonial2').css("display", "none");
        });
        $('#t3').fadeIn("slow", function () {
            $('.testimonial3').css("display", "block");
        });
    }, 6000);

}, 6000);
```

HTML

```
<div id="t1" class="testimonial1">Testimonial 1</div>
<div id="t2" class="testimonial2">Testimonial 2</div>
<div id="t3" class="testimonial3">Testimonial 3</div>
```

CSS

```
.testimonial1 {
    display : block;
}
.testimonial2 {
    display : block;
}
.testimonial3 {
    display : block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  function func1() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.testimonial1').css("display", "none");
      $('.testimonial2').css("display","block");
      func2();
    } ,3000);
  }

  function func2() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.testimonial2').css('display', 'none');
      $('.testimonial3').css('display', 'block');
      func1();
    }, 6000);
  }

  func1();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try looping it with `setInterval`

```
 function play() {
         setTimeout(function(){
        $('.testimonial1').css("display", "none");
        $('.testimonial2').css("display","block");
    } ,3000);



    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.testimonial2').css('display', 'none');
      $('.testimonial3').css('display', 'block');
    }, 6000);
                  }


    setInterval( play , 6000);
```

Comment: Thanks would there be anyway to make the transition less stick, and a bit more animated or flashy?

Comment: @user3907211 - By Animated or Flashy do you mean changes in color to show any kind of difference or do you have any specific animation effect in mind that you are looking for ?

Comment: thanks for your response. Just anything but a hard cut transition. No text color or anything just maybe fadein or out

Comment: @user3907211 - fadeIn and fadeOut transitions added. Updated my answer and the JSFiddle example as well. Please check if it works for you.